# How to foward $refs in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component which should pass everything on to the child. I'm successfully passing `$attrs` and `$listeners` already:

```
<template>
  <el-form v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs" :label-position="labelPosition">
    <slot />
  </el-form>
</template>
```

But I'm unsure how to also forward `$refs` like we can do in [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), so that when using my component like this:

```
<el-form-responsive
  class="form"
  :model="formValues"
  status-icon
  :rules="rules"
  ref="form"
  label-width="auto"
  @submit.native.prevent="submitForm"
>
```

Then `this.$refs.form` is actually a reference to the child `<el-form>`.

I would rather do this transparently, as in you pass exactly the same props to `el-form-responsive` as you would to a `el-form` without needing to know that `refs` has to be passed in a special way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to directly mimic *React's* `ref`. A `ref` attribute in *Vue* is just a string which is used to register a child component reference to the parent's `$refs` object during the render function.

*Here are the links to documentations [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) & [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)*

So basically it's a kind of inverted logic.. instead of passing a ref to a child in Vue we get it from the child into the parent. So it's not really possible at this point to create a grandchild reference, which is what you need.

There are some workarounds though.

**1.** *Quick dirty and not transparent but technically it would work:*
In the parent component, which uses your `el-form-responsive`, on `mounted` hook we could replace the original child reference with the grandchild ref.

*Your `el-form-responsive` component. Template:*

```
<el-form ref="elform">
```

*A parent which uses your `el-form-responsive`. Template:*

```html
<el-form-responsive ref="form">
```

*Script:*

```js
...
mounted () {
  this.$refs.form = this.$refs.form.$refs.elform
}
```

And after this `this.$refs.form` is actually a reference to the granchild `<el-form>`

**2.** *This one would be more elaborate, but probably mach better then the first method*:

In order to make the `el-form-responsive` component really transparent you could expose some of the methods and properties from the child `el-form` component to any potential parent. Something like this:

*`el-form-responsive`. Template:*

```html
<el-form ref="elform">
```

*Script:*

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    whatever: null
  }),
  mounted () {
    this.whatever = this.$refs.elform.whatever
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      this.$refs.elform.submit()
    }
  }
}
```

So then inside some parent `el-form-responsive` could be used like this:

```
<el-form-responsive ref="form">
```

```
...
mounted () {
  const formWhatever = this.$refs.form.whatever // actually `whatever` from `el-form`
  this.$refs.form.submit() // eventually calls submit on `el-form`  
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Since for my requirements I really just needed to call a method in the child component I used your idea to create a method and call the child one via the $ref. And `this.$refs.form.whatever` is not too bad otherwise

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with a custom component with the `script setup` in Vue 3, it's worth nothing that template refs work like [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component).

Essentially, you will have to use `defineExpose` to "expose" your child component data to the parent component

Answer (score 0):

Try this to replace parent's ref with child's , In `el-form-responsive`

```
<template>
  <el-form v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs" :label-position="labelPosition" ref='ref'>
    <slot />
  </el-form>
</template>

mounted () {
  Object.entries(this.$parent.$refs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value === this) {
      this.$parent.$refs[key] = this.$refs.ref
    }
  })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me:

```
mounted() {
   Object.assign(Object.getPrototypeOf(this), this.$refs.formRef)
}
```

warning: insert to `__proto__`,maybe is bad way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).